# cannot run localhost:3000 on meanstack MEANIO, https://github.com/linnovate/mean

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean.io

I downloaded team linnovate's meanio package from github.

I followed all these steps, ran it in command prompt node server, received no errors, installed all node modules, mapped to mongodb with no issues,  [see image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxYlg.png) (win localhost:3000 in the browser, an blank brower page popped open, I received the same problem with OSX] If anyone can kindly help provide clear directions on how to install either with OSX Yosemetie or windows 7 that would be great, thanks

Step 1: npm install -g grunt

Step 2: npm install -g bower

Step 3: npm install node-gyp

Step 4: npm install node-sass --msvs_version=2015

Step 5: npm install -g mean-cli

Step 6: mean init

Step 7: cd

Step 8: npm install

Step 9: node server

Comment: did you investigate teh start script to ensure it's running on 3000 by default?

Comment: yes it is on 3000, the mean favicon icon appears on the tab on the title page

Comment: Does the project need to be built with grunt or similar in order to run?

Comment: did you bower install?

Comment: yes it did, and grunt is running as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by updating node to the latest version (6.9.1 at that time) and start afresh the installation process.

Hope it can help ;)